# Ignoring Blank fields in google forms scripting

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have a google form that users can upload images in and a script that then copies that image to a certain folder that it creates when the form is submitted. currently it stalls on empty uploads where there is no file uploaded only the fields with "leaflet" in are optional, how do I get it to ignore the empty slots?

````
  const folderId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.


  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();






  //Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);


//Rename files
var length=form.getResponses().length;
var id;
var fileUploadQuestionName;
var file;
var name;



//SmallStall
id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('tallbanner1');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('tallbanner2');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[3].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('panel1');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[4].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('panel2');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[5].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('panel3');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[6].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('panel4');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[7].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('logo');



id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[8].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet1');



id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[9].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet2');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[10].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet3');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[11].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet4');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[12].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet5');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[13].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet6');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[14].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet7');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[15].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet8');

id = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[16].getResponse();
file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
name = file.getName();
file.setName('leaflet9');


// Move files to the folder.
itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[2].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[3].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[4].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[5].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[6].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[7].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[8].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[9].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[10].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[11].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[12].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[13].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[14].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[15].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
itemResponses[16].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Instead of hardcoding everything, you can loop through the `itemResponses` array, set the new name from a static array, and move it to the specified folder. Replace everything under `//SmallStall` with this:

```
  const nameArray = ['tallbanner1','tallbanner2','panel1','panel2','panel3','panel4','logo',
                   'leaflet1','leaflet2','leaflet3','leaflet4','leaflet5','leaflet6','leaflet7','leaflet8','leaflet9'];
  
  for (i = 1; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    id = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    name = file.getName();
    file.setName(nameArray[i-1]);
    file.moveTo(folder);
  }
```